# What app sends these push notifications?

Tags: notification-icons

Hope you can see the images. Need to know what app these notifications belong to please.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

To know which notification belongs to which app what you need to do is just long press that notification (after opening notification panel) and it'll reveal the app name or at least it will give you the option to see "App info" which essentially will take you to that app's settings.

Answer (score -1):

It's an google voice assistant daily jokes. See the notification icon in the first screenshot, and compare it with the icon next to the full notification in the second:

[image: see the icon] [image: google assistant]

Comment: Note that the mouth shape (the smile) is different.